# Can I add to my laptop a DDR3L RAM of 1.35v if I already have a DDR3 RAM of 1.5v configured to run at 1.35v?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, compatibility, ddr

I have an MSI GP60 2QF Leopard Pro laptop that has a 4th generation Intel core processor (i5-4210H) and an [8GB Kingston DDR3 SDRAM PC3L-12800S 1600MHz](https://picclick.it/8GB-Kingston-DDR3-SDRAM-PC3L-12800S-1600MHz-Notebook-Speicher-312448889235.html) RAM Memory (couldn't find a better nor original link)

I want to upgrade my RAM memory by adding exactly 8 more GB of RAM of that same model but my problem is that the model I found is not DDR3 but **[DDR3L](https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR16LS11_8.pdf).** Both memories have the same exact specifications, the only difference is the voltage: the RAM I have I don't know why is of 1.5v but is configured to use only 1.35v (apparently, it came like this from the factory) while the one they sell because is DDR3**L** is of 1.35v:

```
sudo dmidecode --type memory | less
```

throws this:

```
Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: C003F863
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: MSI16D3LS1MNG/8G  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.35 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.35 V
```

(CPU-Z also says that I am using a DDR3 memory of 1.35v)

After hours of research I've found in many places statements like this [one](https://www.dell.com/support/article/es-cl/sln153768/what-is-ddr3l-memory?lang=en):

> Systems utilizing Intel 4th generation processors are not backward compatible with regular DDR3 memory modules.

> DDR3 is a single voltage capable memory SoDIMM, which supports 1.5V
> operation only. It is NOT compatible with systems using 4th gen Intel
> processors, which exclusively support 1.35V operation for memory.

In every website I have visited what it says is that DDR3 is not backward compatible with intel 4th generation processors but I am confused because my case is different, by default I have a DDR3, I don't want to add another DDR3 RAM I want to add a DDR3L RAM. Besides, my memory (I don't understand why) is configured with 1.35v.

I have not found someone that has had the same issues so that's why I am asking for help from you guys!

Any help, comment or word will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: It still does not clarify my question, because my memory is of 1.5v and is configured to be 1.35v so idk if thatm will cause me any problems

Comment: It does answer your question. It states that "you cannot put DDR3 in a DDR3L slot" because it can only operate at 1.5v and not 1.35v. It also states that you can put "DDR3L in a DDR3 slot" because DDR3L can operate at 1.35v and 1.5v. As your quote states `4th gen Intel processors, which exclusively support 1.35V operation for memory.` Your slots are exclusively low voltage slots, so you need DDR3L. The link you shared `8GB Kingston DDR3 SDRAM PC3L` PC*3L* denotes it's DDR3L. It's a cryptic output and thing to understand. I was seeing if you'd be able to figure it out given the information.

Comment: @DrZoo Thank you, well I guess they configured my 1.5v RAM to run in 1.35v because of performance or battery reasons but I will buy the RAM that you say which is actually the one I had chosen before but decided to do more research. If you want, write an asnwer so I can mark it as accepted because I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comments :)

Comment: They didn't configure your 1.5v RAM to run in 1.35v. It's actually just behaving as stated in the other answer I linked. It's a DDR3L module which means it can run 1.35v or 1.5v. That's why your output has the min spec of 1.35v and the max spec of 1.5v.

Comment: If you're able to use Newegg here's a link to the RAM you need. [Kingston 8GB 204-Pin DDR3 SO-DIMM DDR3L 1600](https://www.newegg.com/kingston-8gb-204-pin-ddr3-so-dimm/p/N82E16820239697?item=9SIAD8UBJJ3659&source=region&nm_mc=knc-googlemkp-pc&cm_mmc=knc-googlemkp-pc-_-pla-shoppingbest-_-memory+%28notebook+memory%29-_-9SIAD8UBJJ3659&gclid=CjwKCAjw8pH3BRAXEiwA1pvMsQjRNqnVKvB8wmU2fAE71cyEO7W78xUlMQpz6Yl-3XWN_19GDDAs1hoCpnQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: @DrZoo But both either the command I ran and CPU-Z say that I have a DDR3 so that is strange, although it makes more sense what you say because DDR3 memories shouldn't be able to run with 1.35v. I can't use newegg but I'll use a local store of my country so thanks anyway :D. Well I don't mind if you write an aswer, I will also upvote the question you shared once I have enough rep. Thanks again!

Comment: I put the answer back and explained your last question in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It states that "you cannot put DDR3 in a DDR3L slot" because it can only operate at 1.5v and not 1.35v. It also states that you can put "DDR3L in a DDR3 slot" because DDR3L can operate at 1.35v and 1.5v.

As your quote states `4th gen Intel processors, which exclusively support 1.35V operation for memory.`

Your slots are exclusively *low voltage* slots, so you need DDR3L. The link you shared `8GB Kingston DDR3 SDRAM PC3L` PC**3L** denotes it's DDR3L. It's a bit of a cryptic output if you don't quite know how to read and understand all of the information.

Assuming that `dmidecode` behaves like CPU-Z, CPU-Z reads the information from the SPD chip inside the strip of RAM. Many DDR3L strips simply report as DDR3. Looking at the voltage further identifies it as DDR3L. Their only operational difference is DDR3 is strictly 1.5v whereas DDR3L is 1.35v OR 1.5v.

If you're able to use Newegg here's a link to the RAM you need. [Kingston 8GB 204-Pin DDR3 SO-DIMM DDR3L 1600](https://www.newegg.com/kingston-8gb-204-pin-ddr3-so-dimm/p/N82E16820239697?item=9SIAD8UBJJ3659&source=region&nm_mc=knc-googlemkp-pc&cm_mmc=knc-googlemkp-pc-_-pla-shoppingbest-_-memory+%28notebook+memory%29-_-9SIAD8UBJJ3659&gclid=CjwKCAjw8pH3BRAXEiwA1pvMsQjRNqnVKvB8wmU2fAE71cyEO7W78xUlMQpz6Yl-3XWN_19GDDAs1hoCpnQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: " Many DDR3L strips simply report as DDR3. Looking at the voltage further identifies it as DDR3L. Their only operational difference is DDR3 is strictly 1.5v whereas DDR3L is 1.35v OR 1.5v." That really clarified everything. Thx again!